# mistake to convert date time in angular with moment library in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs, jalali-calendar

When I want to convert the Gregorian date to Persian date, it converts the value of the minute in the date conversion to error.

For example I want to convert this date time to Persian date:

`2020-09-14T16:51:00+04:30` must convert to this `1399/06/24 16:51` but when convert date it show me this time `1399/06/24 00:06` it mistake to convert `16:51`, show this: `00:06`.

This is my code to convert date:

```
toPersianDate(date: any, format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM'): string {
    let dateTime;
    const MomentDate = moment(date, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
    dateTime = MomentDate.locale('fa').format('jYYYY/jMM/jDD HH:jMM');
    return dateTime;
}
```

What's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't believe Moment itself has support for Persian dates... Are you using a plugin or another script, like https://github.com/fingerpich/jalali-moment?

Answer (score 1):

the `MM` is used for month formatting, so it is trying to format the minutes into a month.

What you need to use is the small `mm`. Moreover, I don't this you need the `j` before the `mm` as the minutes are the same in Jalali time.

So what you actually need is this: `MomentDate.locale('fa').format('jYYYY/jMM/jDD HH:mm');`

You can read more about the formatting [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/).